# Weird figure numbering in RevTeX article

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

Having some issues with the figure numbering in a paper! Most of the figures are numbered just fine, but there are two who are BOTH being called "figure III", and being numbered with roman numerals, while all the rest are numbered differently and have the correct numbers.

I am compiling online on the latest version of Overleaf (not sure what they use).

Here is a minimal example of what I have:

```
\documentclass[preprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn, tikz}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{array, float}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multirow}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\noindent There is stuff shown in Fig. \ref{Fig:A} and Fig. \ref{Fig:B}. You can see interesting points in Fig. \ref{Fig:A}, and Fig \ref{Fig:B} shows other stuff.\\

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{picture.png}
\caption{A picture showing stuff.}
\end{center}
\label{Fig:A}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{picture-2.png}
\caption{A picture showing other stuff.}
\end{center}
\label{Fig:B}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am going wild trying to fix it so I can submit the article :-)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: The figures are numbered 1 and 2 ... (TL 2016, daily updates, on Linux). Please use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` to make your code compilable, since not everybody has the graphics files at hand. And the labels are outside of the figure environment...

Comment: Ah, Torbjorn answered already

Comment: Yes, he is to fast for us :-)

Answer (score 7):

Seems that when you have the `\caption` inside and the `\label` outside the `center` environment, the `\label` doesn't "see" the `\caption`, and instead attaches itself to something else, likely a `\section`. But it's recommended to use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment anyways (see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651)), so do that and it works fine. Or put the label inside the environment.

```
\documentclass[preprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{float}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\section{ABC}

There is stuff shown in Fig.~\ref{Fig:A} and Fig.~\ref{Fig:B}.
You can see interesting points in Fig.~\ref{Fig:A}, and Fig.~\ref{Fig:B} shows other stuff.

% this will work
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{picture.png}
\caption{A picture showing stuff.}
\label{Fig:A}
\end{figure}

% this will not work    
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{picture-2.png}
\caption{A picture showing other stuff.}
\end{center}
\label{Fig:B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note also that you should in general *never* end a paragraph with `\\ `.

Comment: And note, as Torbjørn already changed in his MWE: use `~` to prevent line wrapping in between the word "Fig." and the following number produced by `\ref{Fig:A}`.

Comment: I'd also add: you don't need to specify the file extension on `\includegraphics`.  They will be added automatically depending on A) if you use old LaTeX or B) newer compilers like pdfLaTeX.  In the first case, it will search for extensions 1) `.ps`, 2) `.eps`, 3) `.ps.gz`, 4) `.eps.gz`.  In the latter case, it will try to append 1) `.jpg`, 2) `.png`, 3) `.pdf`.  To create portable documents, you are advised, to not include the extension.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your awesome comments and help! Especially to Torbjørn for the concise and helpful answer! That fixed my problem perfectly! Kudos.